# When mapping on an ActiveRecord query, my date object stored in the db is converted to a string

Tags: ruby, postgresql, date, object, activerecord

I'm trying to use ActiveRecord's `date.beginning_of_day` but when I'm mapping the query I want to use that method for, the Date obj is being converted to a string.

Here's the code snippet:

```
...
array = where(max_temperature: range).all.map {|condition| condition.date}
    trip_nums = array.map do |date|
      Trip.where(start_date: date.beginning_of_day...date.end_of_day).count
end
...
```

I found this when prying into that scope:

```
pry(Condition)> date.class
=> String
```

And when I check the class within tux:

```
>> Trip.first.start_date.class
=> Date
```

What is going on here?

EDIT: For context, I have a trips table with a start_date column assigned as a Date type

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. The date in my conditions table was set as a string type.